# Examples of UMAP performing poorly

Tags: clustering, dimensionality-reduction, tsne, umap

Can anyone suggest some datasets or examples that would be useful for showing situations where UMAP performs poorly, say in the sense of producing spurious clusters, or missing clusters?  For t-SNE, there are some good examples here https://arxiv.org/pdf/2110.02573.pdf , but when I ran UMAP on them it did a good job.